# Is the laravel str_random url safe?

Tags: string, laravel, url, random

I need to generate a random string to use as part of a URL.

I am using `laravel 5.6` and currently doing this:

```
$url = '/controller/' . str_slug(str_random(8)) . '/review';
```

and I am wondering if I actually need the overhead of `str_slug()`. I can not seem to find anything that indicates if `str_random()` produces URL safe strings or not.

Answer (score 3):

`str_random()` will only contain alphanumeric characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9).

The algorithm takes a string of random btyes, base64 encodes the bytes, and then removes any of the three allowed special characters (`/`, `+`, and `=`).

There's no need for the call to `str_slug()`.

[Here is a link to the function implementation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.6.12/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L289-L302), if you'd like to see the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`str_random` will give **upper** as well as **lower** case characters. Since URLs are generally case insensitive, you will have far less variation in URLs than `str_random` actually generates, but I'm guessing that's not a big issue for you.

`str_slug` will lowercase the random `string`, but that will be the only change it makes, so if you want the same effect you could just use `strtolower(str_random(8))`